# In Scheme, how do you use lambda to create a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, anonymous-recursion

I'm in a Scheme class and I was curious about writing a recursive function without using define. The main problem, of course, is that you cannot call a function within itself if it doesn't have a name.

I did find this example: It's a factorial generator using only lambda.

```
((lambda (x) (x x))
 (lambda (fact-gen)
   (lambda (n)
     (if (zero? n)
         1
         (* n ((fact-gen fact-gen) (sub1 n)))))))
```

But I can't even make sense of the first call, (lambda (x) (x x)): What exactly does that do? And where do you input the value you want to get the factorial of?

This is not for the class, this is just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 18):

`(lambda (x) (x x))` is a function that calls an argument, *x*, on itself.

The whole block of code you posted results in a function of one argument. You could call it like this:

```
(((lambda (x) (x x))
  (lambda (fact-gen)
    (lambda (n)
      (if (zero? n)
          1
          (* n ((fact-gen fact-gen) (sub1 n)))))))
 5)
```

That calls it with 5, and returns 120.

The easiest way to think about this at a high level is that the first function, `(lambda (x) (x x))`, is giving *x* a reference to itself so now *x* can refer to itself, and hence recurse.

Answer (score 11):

The expression `(lambda (x) (x x))` creates a function that, when evaluated with one argument (which must be a function), applies that function with itself as an argument.

Your given expression evaluates to a function that takes one numeric argument and returns the factorial of that argument. To try it:

```
(let ((factorial ((lambda (x) (x x))
                  (lambda (fact-gen)
                    (lambda (n)
                      (if (zero? n)
                          1
                          (* n ((fact-gen fact-gen) (sub1 n)))))))))
  (display (factorial 5)))
```

There are several layers in your example, it's worthwhile to work through step by step and carefully examine what each does.

Answer (score 6):

Basically what you have is a form similar to the Y combinator. If you refactored out the factorial specific code so that any recursive function could be implemented, then the remaining code would be the Y combinator.

I have gone through these steps myself for better understanding.
https://gist.github.com/z5h/238891

If you don't like what I've written, just do some googleing for Y Combinator (the function).

Answer (score 5):

`(lambda (x) (x x))` takes a function object, then invokes that object using one argument, the function object itself.

This is then called with another function, which takes that function object under the parameter name `fact-gen`. It returns a lambda that takes the actual argument, `n`. This is how the `((fact-gen fact-gen) (sub1 n))` works.

You should read the sample chapter (Chapter 9) from [The Little Schemer](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/) if you can follow it. It discusses how to build functions of this type, and ultimately extracting this pattern out into the [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Y_combinator) (which can be used to provide recursion in general).

Answer (score 5):

You define it like this:

```
(let ((fact #f)) 
  (set! fact 
        (lambda (n) (if (< n 2) 1 
                               (* n (fact (- n 1)))))) 
  (fact 5))
```

which is how `letrec` really works. See [LiSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) by Christian Queinnec.

---

In the example you're asking about, the self-application combinator is called ["**U** combinator"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms),

```
(let ((U  (lambda (x) (x x)))
      (h  (lambda (g)
            (lambda (n)
              (if (zero? n)
                  1
                  (* n ((g g) (sub1 n))))))))
  ((U h) 5))
```

The subtlety here is that, because of `let`'s scoping rules, the lambda expressions can not refer to the names being defined.

When `((U h) 5)` is called, it is reduced to `((h h) 5)` application, inside the environment frame created by the `let` form.

Now the application of `h` to `h` creates new environment frame in which `g` points to `h` in the environment above it:

```
(let ((U  (lambda (x) (x x)))
      (h  (lambda (g)
            (lambda (n)
              (if (zero? n)
                  1
                  (* n ((g g) (sub1 n))))))))
  ( (let ((g h))
      (lambda (n)
              (if (zero? n)
                  1
                  (* n ((g g) (sub1 n)))))) 
    5))
```

The `(lambda (n) ...)` expression here is returned from inside that environment frame in which `g` points to `h` above it - as a [*closure* object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). I.e. a function of one argument, `n`, which also remembers the bindings for `g`, `h`, and `U`.

So when this closure is called, `n` gets assigned `5`, and the `if` form is entered:

```
(let ((U  (lambda (x) (x x)))
      (h  (lambda (g)
            (lambda (n)
              (if (zero? n)
                  1
                  (* n ((g g) (sub1 n))))))))
    (let ((g h))
      (let ((n 5))
              (if (zero? n)
                  1
                  (* n ((g g) (sub1 n)))))))
```

The `(g g)` application gets reduced into `(h h)` application because `g` points to `h` defined in the environment frame above the environment in which the closure object was created. Which is to say, up there, in the top `let` form. But we've already seen the reduction of `(h h)` call, which created the closure i.e. the function of one argument `n`, serving as our `factorial` function, which on the next iteration will be called with `4`, then `3` etc.

**Whether it will be a new closure object or same closure object will be reused, depends on a compiler.** This can have an impact on performance, but not on semantics of the recursion.

Answer (score 4):

I like this question.  'The scheme programming language' is a good book.  My idea is from Chapter 2 of that book.

First,  we know this:

```
(letrec ((fact (lambda (n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* (fact (- n 1)) n))))) (fact 5))
```

With `letrec` we can make functions recursively.  And we see when we call `(fact 5)`,  `fact` is already bound to a function.  If we have another function,  we can call it this way `(another fact 5)`,  and now `another` is called *binary* function (my English is not good, sorry).  We can define `another` as this:

```
(let ((another (lambda (f x) .... (f x) ...))) (another fact 5))
```

Why not we define `fact` this way?

```
(let ((fact (lambda (f n) (if (= n 1) 1 (* n (f f (- n 1))))))) (fact fact 5))
```

If `fact` is a *binary* function,  then it can be called with a function `f` and integer `n`,  in which case function `f` happens to be `fact` itself.

If you got all the above, you could write **Y** combinator now,  making a substitution of `let` with `lambda`.

Comment: and in fact, the last variant is exactly the code in question, *uncurried*. IOW, the OP code is a curried version of the last variant here, turning one binary function into two nested one-argument `lambda`s, writing `((f f) x)` instead of `(f f x)`.

Answer (score 3):

With a single lambda it's not possible. But using two or more lambda's it is possible. As, all other solutions are using three lambdas or let/letrec, I'm going to explain the method using two lambdas:

```lisp
((lambda (f x)
   (f f x))
 (lambda (self n)
   (if (= n 0)
       1
       (* n (self self (- n 1)))))
 5)
```

And the output is 120.

Here,

1. `(lambda (f x) (f f x))` produces a lambda that takes two arguments, the first one is a lambda(lets call it `f`) and the second is the parameter(let's call it `x`). Notice, in its body it calls the provided lambda `f` with `f` and `x`.
2. Now, lambda `f`(from point 1) i.e. `self` is what we want to recurse. See, when calling `self` recursively, we also pass `self` as the first argument and `(- n 1)` as the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

> I was curious about writing a recursive function without using define.
>   The main problem, of course, is that you cannot call a function within
>   itself if it doesn't have a name.

A little off-topic here, but seeing the above statements I just wanted to let you know that "without using define" does not mean "doesn't have a name". It is possible to give something a name and use it recursively in Scheme without define.

```
(letrec
  ((fact
     (lambda (n)
       (if (zero? n)
         1
         (* n (fact (sub1 n)))))))
  (fact 5))
```

It would be more clear if your question specifically says "anonymous recursion".

Comment: Yes, but as _let_ is by it‑self, an alias of a _lambda_ expression, this would still be meaningful to be able to give a _lambda_ expression, a local name to be used inside of it‑self. I believe that's what the OP wanted, but I don't know a way to do it in Scheme.

Comment: @Hibou57: although `let` is easy to translate to a lambda expression application, `letrec` is a little harder to do.

Comment: @Hibou57 `(letrec ((name (lambda-expression))) (body))` = `(let ((name (Y (lambda (name) (lambda-expression))))) (body))`. [or something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864862/849891). -- another way is [with `set!`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11833038/849891): `(let ((name #f)) (set! name (lambda-expression)) (body))`.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question because I needed a recursive helper function inside a macro, where one can't use define.

One wants to understand `(lambda (x) (x x))` and the Y-combinator, but named let gets the job done without scaring off tourists:

```
 ((lambda (n)
   (let sub ((i n) (z 1))
     (if (zero? i)
         z
         (sub (- i 1) (* z i)) )))
 5 )
```

One can also put off understanding `(lambda (x) (x x))` and the Y-combinator, if code like this suffices. Scheme, like Haskell and the Milky Way, harbors a massive black hole at its center. Many a formerly productive programmer gets entranced by the mathematical beauty of these black holes, and is never seen again.