# Y combinator discussion in "The Little Schemer"

Tags: scheme, combinators, y-combinator, the-little-schemer

So, I've spent a lot of time reading and re-reading the ending of chapter 9 in *The Little Schemer*, where the applicative Y combinator is developed for the `length` function. I think my confusion boils down to a single statement that contrasts two versions of length (before the combinator is factored out):

```
A:
  ((lambda (mk-length)
     (mk-length mk-length))
   (lambda (mk-length)
     (lambda (l)
       (cond
         ((null? l) 0 )
         (else (add1
                ((mk-length mk-length)
                 (cdr l))))))))

B:
((lambda (mk-length)
      (mk-length mk-length))
    (lambda (mk-length)
      ((lambda (length)
         (lambda (l)
           (cond
             ((null? l) 0)
             (else (add1 (length (cdr l)))))))
       (mk-length mk-length))))
```

[Page 170 (4th ed.)](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=xyO-KLexVnMC&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q&f=false) states that A

> returns a function when we applied it to an argument

while B

> does not return a function

thereby producing an infinite regress of self-applications. I'm stumped by this. If B is plagued by this problem, I don't see how A avoids it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Great question. For the benefit of those without a functioning DrRacket installation <s>(myself included)</s> I'll try to answer it.

First, let's use some sane (short) variable names, easily trackable by a human eye/mind:

```
((lambda (h)     ; A.   
     (h h))            ; apply h to h
 (lambda (g)
     (lambda (lst)
       (if (null? lst) 0
         (add1 
               ((g g) (cdr lst)))))))
```

The first lambda term is what's known as [little omega, or **U** combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms). When applied to something, it causes that term's self-application. Thus the above is equivalent to

```
(let ((h (lambda (g)
           (lambda (lst)
             (if (null? lst) 0
               (add1 ((g g) (cdr lst))))))))
  (h h))
```

When `h` is applied to `h`, new binding is formed:

```
(let ((h (lambda (g)
           (lambda (lst)
             (if (null? lst) 0
               (add1 ((g g) (cdr lst))))))))
  (let ((g h))
    (lambda (lst)
            (if (null? lst) 0
              (add1 ((g g) (cdr lst)))))))
```

Now there's nothing to apply anymore, so the inner `lambda` form is returned — along with the hidden linkages to the environment frames (i.e. those `let` bindings) up above it.

This pairing of a lambda expression with its defining environment is known as [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)). To the outside world it is just another function of one parameter, `lst`. No more reduction steps left to perform there at the moment.

Now, when that closure — our `list-length` function — will be called, execution will eventually get to the point of `(g g)` self-application, and the same reduction steps as outlined above will again be performed (recalculating *the* *same* closure). But not earlier.

---

Now, the authors of that book want to arrive at the **Y** combinator, so they apply some code transformations to the first expression, to somehow arrange for that self-application `(g g)` to be performed automatically — so we may write the recursive function application in the normal manner, `(f x)`, instead of having to write it as `((g g) x)` for all recursive calls:

```
((lambda (h)     ; B.
     (h h))            ; apply h to h
 (lambda (g)
   ((lambda (f)           ; 'f' to become bound to '(g g)',
      (lambda (lst) 
        (if (null? lst) 0
          (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))  ; here: (f x) instead of ((g g) x)!
    (g g))))                       ; (this is not quite right)
```

Now after few reduction steps we arrive at

```
(let ((h (lambda (g)
           ((lambda (f)    
              (lambda (lst) 
                (if (null? lst) 0
                  (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))
            (g g)))))
  (let ((g h))
    ((lambda (f)
       (lambda (lst)
            (if (null? lst) 0
              (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))
     (g g))))
```

which is equivalent to

```
(let ((h (lambda (g)
           ((lambda (f)    
              (lambda (lst) 
                (if (null? lst) 0
                  (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))
            (g g)))))
  (let ((g h))
    (let ((f (g g)))           ; problem! (under applicative-order evaluation)
       (lambda (lst)
            (if (null? lst) 0
              (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))))
```

And here comes trouble: the self-application of `(g g)` is performed too early, *before* that inner lambda can be even returned, as a closure, to the run-time system. We only want it to be reduced when the execution gets to that point *inside* the lambda expression, *after* the closure was called. To have it reduced before the closure is even created is ridiculous. A *subtle* error. :)

Of course, since `g` is bound to `h`, `(g g)` is reduced to `(h h)` and we're back again where we started, applying `h` to `h`. Looping.

---

Of course the authors are aware of this. They want *us* to understand it too.

So the culprit is simple — it is the [applicative order of evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order): *evaluating* the argument *before* the binding is formed of the function's formal parameter and its argument's *value*.

That code transformation wasn't quite right, then. It would've worked under [normal order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Normal_order) where arguments aren't evaluated in advance.

This is remedied easily enough by "[eta-expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion)", which delays the application until the actual call point: `(lambda (x) ((g g) x))` actually says: "***will*** call `((g g) x)` when called upon with an argument of `x`".

And this is actually what that code transformation should have been in the first place:

```
((lambda (h)     ; C.
     (h h))            ; apply h to h
 (lambda (g)
   ((lambda (f)           ; 'f' to become bound to '(lambda (x) ((g g) x))',
      (lambda (lst) 
        (if (null? lst) 0
          (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))  ; here: (f x) instead of ((g g) x)
    (lambda (x) ((g g) x)))))
```

Now that next reduction step can be performed:

```
(let ((h (lambda (g)
           ((lambda (f)    
              (lambda (lst) 
                (if (null? lst) 0
                  (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))
            (lambda (x) ((g g) x))))))
  (let ((g h))
    (let ((f (lambda (x) ((g g) x))))       ; here it's OK
      (lambda (lst)
            (if (null? lst) 0
              (add1 (f (cdr lst))))))))
```

and the closure `(lambda (lst) ...)` is formed and returned without a problem, and when `(f (cdr lst))` is called (inside the closure) it is reduced to `((g g) (cdr lst))` just as we wanted it to be.

---

Lastly, we notice that `(lambda (f) (lambda (lst ...))` expression in `C.` doesn't depend on any of the `h` and `g`. So we can take it out, make it an argument, and be left with ... the **Y** combinator:

```
( ( (lambda (rec)            ; D.
      ( (lambda (h) (h h))  
        (lambda (g)
          (rec  (lambda (x) ((g g) x))))))   ; applicative-order Y combinator
    (lambda (f)
        (lambda (lst) 
          (if (null? lst) 0
            (add1 (f (cdr lst)))))) )
  (list 1 2 3) )                            ; ==> 3
```

So now, calling **Y** on a function is equivalent to making a recursive definition out of it:

```
( y (lambda (f) (lambda (x) .... (f x) .... )) ) 
===  define f = (lambda (x) .... (f x) .... )
```

... but using `letrec` (or named let) is *better* — more efficient, [defining the closure in self-referential environment frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719004/in-scheme-how-do-you-use-lambda-to-create-a-recursive-function/11833038#11833038). The whole **Y** thing is a theoretical exercise for the systems where that is not possible — i.e. where it is not possible to *name* things, to create *bindings* with names *"pointing"* to things, *referring* to things.

*Incidentally, the ability to* point *to things is what distinguishes the higher primates from the rest of the animal kingdom ⁄ living creatures, or so I hear.* :)

Comment: thanks!! :)  I think about adding the final step of deriving the Y itself ... it's the next logical thing to do. I remember myself mystified by the whole Y thing/mystery. Needlessly so. Too often it is  presented ex-machina. There are all kinds of metaphorical descriptions, but not the actual derivation. I like to see the justification, and then the derivation. In *small steps*. :)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was stuck on this very part, and I had a feeling that the first `lambda` expression mentioned above was also equivalent to the `let` form, but I wasn't entirely sure until reading this - let alone that it was called the "omega combinator". This information would have been helpful. I think I will still have to spend some time tracing the output of the Y-combinator, but it feels much less muddy than (in my opinion) the authors' rather lackluster explanation of this concept.

Comment: welcome. :) the *"little"* explanation as is usual in the *"Little"* books ... :) They leave it to readers to form explanations for themselves; I personally don't know if that's such a great idea; or else there wouldn't be universities and textbooks today... we're supposed to stand on the giant's *shoulders*, not in their *footsteps*... also, it's [the *little* omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms): " ω := λx.x x ; Ω := ω ω " and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega calls the `Ω`  an "omega combinator" so that might have not been exactly right.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification. One more question - is the second `lambda` in (A) also an example of a *little* omega-combinator? I.e. does `(lambda (g) (rest-of-function))` resemble the first `(lambda (h) (h h))`. I am trying to understand how calling `(g g)` results in recursion on the second `lambda` expression...

Comment: little-omega is just a name commonly used to refer to `(λx.x x)` term.  The second `lambda` in `A` is certainly something else - it is the definition of the recursive procedure written in a certain way to be "jump-started" by self-application. Since this `(lambda(g) ...)` is applied to itself, the variable binding is formed where `g` refers to the whole lambda term `(lambda(g) ...)`. The later call `(g g)` is thus the same self-application, with the same results.

Comment: @Dylan Turns out, little-omega is a.k.a. [U-combinator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16258308/849891).

Comment: @WillNess I thought the U combinator was [`(λx.λy.y (x x y))`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Standard_terms).

Comment: @AaditMShah I've noticed that myself yesterday, on the Wikipedia LC page. It used to be different, or this is what I remember anyway. Also, there's [U combinator group](http://www.ucombinator.org/) in Utah university CS department - which I hit by googling some years back - that uses U that way, so I too been using it that way since. So now I don't know what's what. Need to dig through primary sources maybe.

Comment: @AaditMShah I've reverted that edit on WP LC page. It gave no sources, but the `\x.xx` form appears on the front page of a respectable research institution.

Answer (score 24):

To see what happens, use the stepper in DrRacket.
The stepper allows you to see all intermediary steps (and to go back and forth).

Paste the following into DrRacket:

```
(((lambda (mk-length)
    (mk-length mk-length))
  (lambda (mk-length)
    (lambda (l)
      (cond
        ((null? l) 0 )
        (else (add1
               ((mk-length mk-length)
                (cdr l))))))))
 '(a b c))
```

Then choose the teaching language "Intermediate Student with lambda".
Then click the stepper button (the green triangle followed by a bar).

This is what the first step looks like:

[image]

Then make an example for the second function and see what goes wrong.