# my ordered predicate won't work

Tags: sorting, scheme, racket

This function is supposed to return `#t` if the list `e` is incrementally ordered.
The function doesn't work and I can't fix it.

```
(define (ordered e)
  (if (or (null? e) (> length(e) 1))
      #t
      (if (> (car e) (cadr e))
          #f
          (ordered (cdr e)))))
```

Comment: Dan has given the reason why your program fails. In order to find such an error the stepper in DrRacket is a useful tool to know. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499514/y-combinator-discussion-in-the-little-schemer/10500358#10500358

Comment: The function could also be written as `(define (ordered e) (apply > e))`.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is in the question is wrong, it's easier (and less error-prone) to simply state that a list is ordered if it has less than two elements. That's what was causing problems in your code, because the base case is ill-defined, your procedure enters in the second case when it shouldn't. When the list has less than two elements, you can't use `cadr`. To fix your implementation do this:

```
(define (ordered e) 
  (if (< (length e) 2)
      #t 
      (if (> (car e) (cadr e))
          #f 
          (ordered (cdr e)))))
```

You can express the solution to this problem more concisely by using `cond`, and you can avoid using `length` (which depending on the implementation could be an `O(n)` operation) like this:

```
(define (ordered e)
  (cond ((or (null? e) (null? (cdr e))) #t)
        ((> (car e) (cadr e)) #f)
        (else (ordered (cdr e)))))
```

Comment: @Lara I updated my answer with more details and with a correct implementation of the code in your question, take a look