# Unable to get implementation of Y combinator working

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, combinators, y-combinator

Here's the code ([also here](http://www.slideshare.net/fullscreen/yinwang0/reinventing-the-ycombinator/1)):

```
#lang racket
(define poorY
  ((lambda length
    (lambda (ls)
      (cond
        [(null? ls) 0]
        [else (add1 ((length length) (cdr ls)))])))
  (lambda length
    (lambda (ls)
      (cond
        [(null? ls) 0]
        [else (add1 ((length length) (cdr ls)))])))))
```

When I run it:

```
> (poorY '(9 7 8))
. . application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(#<procedure>)
  arguments...:
   '(#<procedure>)
```

The screenshot looks like this:

[image]

I'm using DrRacket as the repl.
What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 9):

There should be parentheses around `length` :

```
(define poorY
  ((lambda (length)  ;; here
    (lambda (ls)
      (cond
        [(null? ls) 0]
        [else (add1 ((length length) (cdr ls)))])))
  (lambda (length)   ;; and here
    (lambda (ls)
  ......
```

Instead of typing the same long lambda expression twice, you can also try

```
(define poorY
  ((lambda (f) (f f))
   (lambda (length)
     (lambda (ls)
       (cond
         [(null? ls) 0]
         [else (add1 ((length length) (cdr ls)))])))))
```

See also [Y combinator discussion in "The Little Schemer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499514/y-combinator-discussion-in-the-little-schemer/11864862#11864862) .