# Meaning of letrec in Scheme/Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, let, letrec

So as far as I understand, the following: `let`, `let*`, `letrec` and `letrec*` are synthetics sugars used in Scheme/Racket.

Now, if I have a simple program:

```
(let ((x 1)
      (y 2))
     (+ x y))
```

It is translated into:

```
((lambda (x y) (+ x y)) 1 2)
```

If I have:

```
(let* ((x 1)
      (y 2))
     (+ x y))
```

It is translated into:

```
((lambda (x) ((lambda (y) (+ x y))) 2) 1)
```

Now, for my first question, I understand the meaning of a `letrec` expression, which enables one to use recursion inside a let, but I do not understand how exactly it is done. What is `letrec` translated to?

For example, what will

```
(letrec ((x 1)
      (y 2))
     (+ x y))
```

be translated into?

The second question is similar about `letrec*` - But for `letrec*` I do not understand how exactly it differs from `letrec`? And also, what will a `letrec*` expression be translated into?

Comment: `letrec` is not translated into anything. `letrec` is a primitive form of the language. (And, for what it’s worth, in Racket, `let` is *also* a primitive form in Racket, not a macro on top of `lambda`, but that’s much more of a subjective design choice.)

Comment: Whether or not its translated is one thing. But can't there be an equivalent expression for `letrec`, the same way there is an equivalent expression for `let` and `let*` (such as I specified in my examples)?

Comment: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719004/in-scheme-how-do-you-use-lambda-to-create-a-recursive-function/11833038#11833038) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003518/confused-by-the-difference-between-let-and-let-in-scheme/15006018#15006018) . (disclaimer: both are my answers). the last one actually has  two possible expansions, for the `letrec` and `letrec*`. (so, this might even be a duplicate...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the paper "Fixing Letrec: A Faithful Yet Efficient Implementation
of Scheme’s Recursive Binding Construct" by Oscar Waddell, Dipanwita Sarkar, and,
R. Kent Dybvig.

The paper starts with a simple version and proceeds to explain a more sophisticated expansion:

https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/fixing-letrec.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Since you example does not have any procedures and no real expressions I'd say you could implement it as:

```
(let ((x 1) (y 2))
  (+ x y))
```

But to support the intention of the form a basic implementaiton might do something like this:

```
(let ((x 'undefined) (y 'undefined))
  (let ((tmpx 1) (tmpy 2))
    (set! x tmpx)
    (set! y tmpy))
  (+ x y))
```

Now. `letrec` is for lambdas to be able to call themselves by the name. So imagine this:

```
(let ((fib (lambda (n) 
             (if (< n 2) n 
                 (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))))
      (fib 10))
```

It's important to understand that this does not work and why. Transforming it into a `lambda` call makes it so easy to see:

```
((lambda (fib)
   (fib 10))
 (lambda (n) 
   (if (< n 2) n 
       (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
```

Somehow you need to evaluate the lambda after `fib` is created. Lets imagine we do this:

```
(let ((fib 'undefined))
  (set! fib (lambda (n) 
              (if (< n 2) n 
                  (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2))))))
  (fib 10))
```

Alternatively you can do it with a [Z combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37492667/1565698) to make it pure:

```
(let ((fib (Z (lambda (fib)
                (lambda (n) 
                  (if (< n 2) n 
                      (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))))))  
  (fib 10))
```

This requires more work by the implementation, but at least you do without mutation. To make it work with several mutual recursive bindings probably takes some more work but I'm convinced its doable.

These are the only two ways to do this properly. I know `clojure` has a `recur` which imitates recursion but in reality is a a goto.

For variables that do not make closures from the `letrec` bindings they work as `let` and later more like `let*` since Soegaards answer about fix is backwards compatible and some has adapted it. If you write compatible code though you should not be tempted to assume this.