# how to analyze the equivalent receiver in call/cc?

Tags: scheme, racket, continuations, callcc

I am reading the book *Scheme and the Art of Programming*, but cannot think of an answer to the following question:

If *r* is

```
(escaper (lambda (continuation) (continuation body))
```

in `(... (call/cc r) ...)`, when can *r* be rewritten as

```
(lambda (continuation) body)
```

Comment: `escaper` is not part of Scheme. it is defined by that book, *Scheme and the Art of Programming*, so it is important to mention it. *" `escaper` turns its argument procedure into similarly defined 'escape' procedure (a.k.a. 'continuation'), which, when invoked, its result becomes the result of the entire computation. Anything awaiting the result [of that escape procedure's invocation] is ignored."* (slightly copy-edited)

Comment: `(call/cc r)` can appear anywhere in that expression. that's what `... ...` signify.

Comment: if ```r``` is ```(escaper (lambda (continuation) (continuation body)))```, result of ```(r continuation)``` is still ```(continuation body)``` since ```continuation``` is also an escape procedure and invoked first. it is no difference that r is ```(escaper (lambda (continuation) (continuation body)))``` or ```(lambda (continuation) (continuation body))```. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: you repeat the conclusion of my answer. :) I was a bit more careful at arriving at it. I give translation and work through it carefully. But if it is so clear for you, why have you asked? :) but it's good that you asked, it gave me a chance to work through this exercise. :) cheers!

Comment: i can solve the question preceding the one i asked. but feel confused in this one. after reading the first line of your answer, i rethought this question, understood why it is always.

Comment: so my answer was useful?  ;)

Comment: @WillNess yeah, of course! u inspired me!

Comment: glad to be of help. :) (notice the re-writes with `let`. it often helps me to understand code when I do such re-writes, like [with y-combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11864862/849891))

Comment: @WillNess thanks for reminding :) i will try to take in the skills u used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: *always*.

`escaper` is not part of Scheme. It is defined by that book, *Scheme and the Art of Programming*, thus:

> *" `escaper` turns its argument procedure into similarly defined 'escape' procedure (a.k.a. 'continuation'), which, when invoked, its result becomes the result of the entire computation. Anything awaiting the result [of that escape procedure's invocation] is ignored."* <sub>(slightly copy-edited)</sub>

The result of `(continuation body)` <sup>*in the " `escaper`-ed" version of `(lambda (c..n) (c..n body))`*</sup> *would* be returned directly into the top level, except, `continuation` does not *return*. It *jumps* into *its* destination context `(1)`, i.e. *that* which awaits the result of the `(call/cc r)` call, because *this* `continuation` is set up by that call to `call/cc`:

```
           ;; (0)   -- top level
             (... 
                  ;; (1)  <-----------------------------------\
                    (call/cc r)  ;; r = (escaper (lambda (continuation)
                                 ;;                 (continuation body)))
                         ...)
===
           ;; (0)   -- top level
             (... 
                  ;; (1)  
                    (continuation--0                       ;; set up by `escaper`
                      ((lambda (continuation)
                            (continuation body))
                        continuation--1))                   ;; set up by call/cc
                         ...)
===
           ;; (0)   -- top level
             (... 
                  ;; (1)  
                    (continuation--0
                       (let ((continuation continuation--1))   ;; by application of `lambda`
                         (continuation body)))
                         ...)
```

So if `body` *returns*, that result is passed into `(1)` by `continuation--1`; and if `body` *calls* `continuation` with a value, that value is passed into `(1)` by `continuation--1`. Nothing is returned to `continuation--0`, so its jump is never triggered.

And in

```
           ;; (0)
             (... 
                  ;; (1)
                    (call/cc (lambda (continuation) body))
                         ...)
===
           ;; (0)
             (... 
                  ;; (1)
                    (let ((continuation continuation--1)) 
                       body)
                         ...)
```

exactly the same thing happens: if `body` *returns*, that result is simply returned into `(1)`; and if `body` *calls* `continuation` with a value, that value is passed into `(1)` by `continuation--1`.