# Scheme - fibonacci series with nested lambda

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, fibonacci, y-combinator

Inspired [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719004/in-scheme-how-do-you-use-lambda-to-create-a-recursive-function) post .

I trying to implement a fibonacci series with nested lambda  -

```
(( (lambda (x) (x x)) ;; evaluate x on x
    ((lambda (fibo-gen)) ;; fibo-gen get another func as arg
    (lambda (N it second first)
     (cond  ;; here the body of the above func ..
       ((= N 1) 1)
       ((= N 1) 1)
       ((= N it) (+ second first))
       (else (fibo-gen (+ it 1) (+ second first) (second)))
       )
     )
    )
   )
 5  1 1 1)
```

It's prompts `r5rs:body: no expression in body in: (r5rs:body)`

By my examination each function has a "body" here  , so what I did wrong ?

Note that the implementation I trying to do here is iterative mode which avoid re-calculate previous series  ..

**Edit  :**

Another mode which also works  -

```
(( (lambda (x) (x x)) ;; evaluate x on x
    (lambda (fibo-gen) ;; fibo-gen body use another lambda ..
    (lambda (N it second first)
     (cond  ;; here the body of the above func ..
       ((= N 1) 1)
       ((= N 2) 1)
       ((= N it) second)
       (else ((fibo-gen fibo-gen) N (+ it 1) (+ second first) second))
       )
     )
    )
   )
 5 1 1 1)
 => 8
```

Comment: `lamba` probably doesn't help.

Comment: It was just typo .. still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is *quite* a contrived way to calculate fibonacci, but nevertheless possible:

```
(((lambda (x) (x x))
  (lambda (fib-gen)
    (lambda (it second first)
      (if (zero? it)
          first
          ((fib-gen fib-gen) (sub1 it) (+ first second) second)))))
 10 1 0) ; here n = 10

=> 55
```

If you're aiming for a general way for writing a recursive function without using `define`, first implement the [Y-Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator):

```
(define (Y X)
  ((lambda (proc) (proc proc))
   (lambda (proc)
     (X (lambda args
          (apply (proc proc) args))))))
```

With this, you can write anonymous recursive procedures with a variable number of arguments, for example:

```
((Y
  (lambda (fib-gen)
    (lambda (it second first)
      (if (zero? it)
          first
          (fib-gen (sub1 it) (+ first second) second)))))
 10 1 0)  ; here n = 10

=> 55
```

Comment: Does the `(fib-gen fib-gen)` is must here  ? 
Why not just inc the `N` each iteration as I tried ?

Comment: @URL87 that's the _anonymous_ recursive call, without it there will not be any "iteration". So yes, it has to go there.

Answer (score 1):

```
(lambda (fibo-gen))
```

in the second line has no body.